# Session variable 'unsetted' automatically + with a bit of code

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies, session-variables

Why the session isnt saved? After reload the session variable 'mucciusersess' disapears! Why? Thanks...

```
I have an cookie on client-side with value like 'mucciuserid' set to '122341212'

session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION['usersess'];
//    if session var not already exists --> get from cookie and set
if(!isset($userid)) {

     $usercokie = $_COOKIE['userid'];
             echo $usercokie.' < > '.$userid;
     $_SESSION['usersess'] = $usercokie;
     $userid = $_SESSION['usersess'];
             echo '-'.$userid;  
}
```

Comment: `echo $usercokie` i think `$usercokie` has blank value

Comment: tested before $usercokie is ok

Comment: run only above code in a different file check there output.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Sure but i think if condition is being true please try once like this:**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION['mucciusersess'];
//    if session var not already exists --> get from cookie and set

if(!$userid>0) {

     $usercokie = $_COOKIE['mucciuserid'];
             echo $usercokie.' < > '.$userid;
     $_SESSION['mucciusersess'] = $usercokie;
     $userid = $_SESSION['mucciusersess'];
             echo '-'.$userid;  
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah the problem is with that condition but ('!$userid>0') why? EX: id = 365 what is the inverse of 365? error... and the error > 0 ...something is bad

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem was with $_COOKIE that somethimes returned false so i solved with:

```
if(isset($usercokie)) {
            $_SESSION['usersess'] = $usercokie;
            $userid = $_SESSION['usersess'];         
}}
```